# Вывести параметры из stdclass object / перевести в массив

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3

Подскажите как вывести параметры из stdclass object, или перевести в массив

Получаю данные с модуля Joomla

```
jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' ); // подключаем нужный класс, один раз на странице, перед первым выводом
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_seo_link'); // получаем объект модуля, 
$param = json_decode($module->params); // декодирует JSON с параметрами модуля
    echo '<pre>';
        print_r($param); // смотрим все параметры
    echo '</pre>';
```

Получается в таком формате
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так пробовал вывести

```
     <?php foreach ($param as $item) : ?>

      <p><?php echo $item->example_text; ?></p>
      <p> <?php echo $item->example_textarea; ?></p>


<?php endforeach; ?>
```

и так

```
 echo $params->get('example_text');
    echo $params->get('example_textarea');
```

Но ничего не получается, подскажите как правильно?

Comment: У меня только один вопрос. Зачем? Самое простое `json_decode(json_encode($obj), true);` true - важно. Можно замутить рекурсию, но лень.

Comment: в вашем случае: `$param = json_decode($module->params);` -> `$param = json_decode($module->params, true);` читайте доки!!!

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
Нужно для того чтобы вывести данные из модуля, использую форму Subform form field type 
Строка $param = json_decode($module->params); у меня уже прописана
после нее stdClass Object и появился,
можно как то по другому получить параметры из модуля?

Comment: Вы мой второй комментарий внимательно перечитайте. Очень внимательно.

Comment: Извините, перечитал, увидел поправку.
Но таким способом все равно не получается вывести параметры `echo $params->get('example_text')`
или таким
`<?php foreach ($param as $item) : ?>
  
      <p><?php echo $item->example_text; ?></p>
      <p> <?php echo $item->example_textarea; ?></p>
    
 
<?php endforeach; ?>`
как правильно вывести?
Благодарю вас за помощь!

Comment: `$params['fieldname']['fieldname1']['example_text']`?

Comment: @E_p, нет,  это не ассоциативный массив, а простой object в несколько уровней...

Comment: @Arsen смотря в каком варианте ;).

Comment: @E_p  Вывод исходных параметров Joomla module - это всегда Object , что потом будет, этого никто не знает ))

Comment: Пробовал  вывести параметры данным способом `echo $params['fieldname']['fieldname0']['example_text'];` получаю только белый экран 
Получилось вывести так `$params->fieldname->fieldname1->example_text `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вся суть проблемы в том, что вы пытаетесь получить данные в `foreach` ?! Зачем вы параметры вставляете в цикл ?
`$param = json_decode($module->params);` 
В `$params` уже находится `object` и вы можете просто получить все данные без цикла:

`$params->fieldname->fieldname1->example_text` 
или  
`$params->fieldname->fieldname1->example_textarea`

> Дополнено

```
for($i=1; $i <=10; $i++){
$key = 'fieldname'.$i;
echo $param->fieldname->$key->example_textarea;
}
```

Comment: в цикле потому что нужно вывести данные с нескольких форм,
но при добавлении еще одной ссылки цифра увеличивается  `fieldname2`  и тд. скрин (http://prntscr.com/fc7nab)
Попробовал сделать так
`for($i=1; $i <=10; $i++)
   echo  $param->fieldname->fieldname+$i->example_textarea;`
получаю только нули.
подскажите как вывести все данные?

Comment: @SerhiyBilik -  такое решение    fieldname+$i это некорректно, обновлю свой ответ